# Bad access with a fixed size array and index in range

Tags: swift

I'm getting crashes from a fixed size array even though I thought I'd protected the index from going out of range. The array updates in a loop, like a ring buffer.

This crashes reliably when the array size is 1000, but I've not managed to get it to crash when it's 500 or fewer.
**EDIT:** It has now crashed with an array size of 500, so the previous statement is no longer true.

I'm wondering whether this is compiler 'optimisation'... and what to do if it is. Any ideas gratefully received.

```
struct ZeroCrossing {
  //The integer index of the second sample (cross over is between two samples)
  var index: UInt
  //The highest amplitude peak (negative or positive) between this and the previous crossing
  let previousPeak: Float
  //The interpolated crossover point between the two sample indices
  let indexWithOffset: Double
}

class CrossingBuffer {
  private var array: [ZeroCrossing]
  private let size: Int
  private var nextWriteIndex = 0
  private var full: Bool {
    nextWriteIndex >= size
  }

  init(size: Int) {
    self.size = size
    array = [ZeroCrossing](repeating: ZeroCrossing(index: 0, previousPeak: 0, indexWithOffset: 0), count: size)
    array.reserveCapacity(size)
  }
  
  public func write(_ val: ZeroCrossing) {
    array[nextWriteIndex % size] = val
    nextWriteIndex += 1
  }
    
  public func getAfterIndex(_ refIndex: Double) -> [ZeroCrossing]? {
    if !full { return nil }
    var subArray = [ZeroCrossing]()
    let lastElementIndex = nextWriteIndex - 1
    for i in 0...size - 1 {

      //   CRASHES ON NEXT LINE !!!
      let thisCrossing = array[(lastElementIndex - i) % size]

      if thisCrossing.indexWithOffset > refIndex {
        subArray.append(thisCrossing)
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
    return subArray.reversed()
  }
  
  public func reset() {
    array = [ZeroCrossing](repeating: ZeroCrossing(index: 0, previousPeak: 0, indexWithOffset: 0), count: size)
    nextWriteIndex = 0
  }
}
```

The backtrace ends with the following

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1016dc008)
    frame #0: 0x000000018bf5c090 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_retain + 60
    frame #1: 0x000000018bf9c704 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_bridgeObjectRetain + 56
  * frame #2: 0x0000000100838e50 CrossingBuffer.getAfterIndex(refIndex=431975.76999999583, self=0x00000002800a86f0) at CrossingBuffer.swift:97:31
    frame #3: 0x00000001007cd704 correlate(self=0x000000010130e5c0) at PitchEngine.swift:146:52
    frame #4: 0x00000001007a155c correlate(self=0x0000000283b91200) at TunerEngine.swift:57:39
    frame #5: 0x00000001007a1bd8 @objc correlate() at <compiler-generated>:0
```

But what's strange is that I can access the element from the debug console using the same index reference as the line it crashed on:

```
(lldb) print (lastElementIndex - i) % size
(Int) $R4 = 838
(lldb) print array.count
(Int) $R5 = 1000
(lldb) print array[(lastElementIndex - i) % size]
(ZeroCrossing) $R6 = (index = 438691, previousPeak = 0.0251232013, indexWithOffset = 438690.12000000477)
```

Update: additional code to illustrate crashing, it seems that in my case it only crashes when the array size is > 638. There may need to be some noise for the mic to pick up to instigate the crash:

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

final class AudioTap {
  
  private var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
  private var windowIndex: UInt = 0
  private var lastPeak: Float = 0
  private var lastSample: Sample?
  public var minPeakSize: Float = 0.005
  
  // Size of crossingBuffer changes crashing behavior
  private var crossingBuffer = CrossingBuffer(size: 2000)
  
  private var lastSeekIndex: Double = 0.0
  
  private var timer: Timer?
  
  init() {
    installTunerTap()
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
      try audioEngine.start()
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("AVAudioEngine error on start: \(error.domain), \(error)")
    }
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
      timeInterval: 0.01,
      target: self,
      selector: #selector(getNext),
      userInfo: nil,
      repeats: true)
  }
  
  private func installTunerTap() {
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    inputNode.installTap( onBus: 0,
                          bufferSize: 1000,
                          format: nil,
                          block: { buffer, when in
      let sampleCount = Int(buffer.frameLength)
      var sampleIndex = 0
      
      while (sampleIndex < sampleCount) {
        if let val = buffer.floatChannelData?.pointee[sampleIndex]{
          let sample = Sample(index: self.windowIndex, val: val)
          self.update(sample: sample)
        }
        self.windowIndex += 1
        sampleIndex += 1
      }
    })
  }
  
  private func update(sample: Sample) {
    lastPeak = abs(sample.val) > abs(lastPeak) ? sample.val : lastPeak
    if let last = lastSample {
      if last.val * sample.val < 0 && abs(lastPeak) > minPeakSize { // this is a zero crossing
        let offset = Double(sample.index) + Double(round((sample.val/(last.val - sample.val)) * 100) / 100)
        
        let crossing = ZeroCrossing(
          index: sample.index,
          previousPeak: lastPeak,
          indexWithOffset: offset
        )
        crossingBuffer.write(crossing)
        lastPeak = 0
      }
    }
    lastSample = sample
  }
  
  @objc func getNext() {
    if let arr = crossingBuffer.getAfterIndex(lastSeekIndex) {
      if let s = arr.last {
        lastSeekIndex = s.indexWithOffset
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn’t get this to crash as you did, perhaps you could share some more info on your setup. I did manage to get a crash when I set the size to 5000 but that was in the `write` function

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Joakim, I've added some code with the calls that should demonstrate the crashing.

Comment: From the documentation of AVAudioNode, _"The framework may invoke the tapBlock on a thread other than the main thread."_. Could it be that you access the CrossingBuffer from two threads simultaneously, this could explain why you only see this when `size` is large enough because then `CrossingBuffer.getAfterIndex` takes long enough for a clash to occur? Note, I have no experience with AVAudioEngine myself so I don't know how it really behaves but was only looking for something suspicious in the code

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, in the complete app that is a possibility although I thought that by only writing in one thread (but reading from others) I'd be protected from clashes. Also I created a project using only the code above and it still crashes. And it doesn't seem random, if this was a clash I'd expect the crashes to get more frequent with each increase of array size. I can only get it to crash with a size of 639 after which it crashes reliably.

Comment: After many tries, it just crashed with an array size of 500, which means my last comment wasn't correct. I'll update the main post.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Looks like you could well be correct. After adding an NSLock to CrossingBuffer and wrapping each read and write in a lock / unlock the crashing appears to have stopped. I'll test for a while and post the solution if it proves to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not crashed after many uses so I'm going to call this one fixed. Here's the updated CrossingBuffer code with the NSLock implemented. Thanks for the help @JoakimDainelson:

```
class CrossingBuffer {
  private var array: [ZeroCrossing]
  
  // NSLock Added
  var lock = NSLock()

  private let size: Int
  private var nextWriteIndex = 0
  private var full: Bool {
    nextWriteIndex >= size
  }

  init(size: Int) {
    self.size = size
    array = [ZeroCrossing](repeating: ZeroCrossing(index: 0, previousPeak: 0, indexWithOffset: 0), count: size)
    array.reserveCapacity(size)
  }
  
  public func write(_ val: ZeroCrossing) {
    //Lock before write
    lock.lock()
    array[nextWriteIndex % size] = val
    //Unlock
    lock.unlock()
    nextWriteIndex += 1
  }
    
  public func getAfterIndex(_ refIndex: Double) -> [ZeroCrossing]? {
    if !full { return nil }
    var subArray = [ZeroCrossing]()
    let lastElementIndex = nextWriteIndex - 1
    for i in 0...size - 1 {

        //   Was Crashing here, now wrapped in lock / unlock

        lock.lock()
        let thisCrossing = array[(lastElementIndex - i) % size]
        lock.unlock()

      if thisCrossing.indexWithOffset > refIndex {
        subArray.append(thisCrossing)
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
    return subArray.reversed()
  }
  
  public func reset() {
    array = [ZeroCrossing](repeating: ZeroCrossing(index: 0, previousPeak: 0, indexWithOffset: 0), count: size)
    nextWriteIndex = 0
  }
}
```